# How can I replace @ symbol just from href?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a condition where I wrap the @username values in an anchor to make them clickable

```
const text = 'test @username'
const replaced = text.replace(/(@[a-z_\d]+)/ig, '<a class="tag_user" href="/profile/$1" >$1</a> ')
console.log(replaced)
```

Currently, the output was like

```
test <a class="tag_user" href="/profile/@username" >@username</a>
```

And I want to achieve something like:

```
test <a class="tag_user" href="/profile/username" >@username</a>
```

Can anybody have any idea how can I achieve the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to remove `@` from the capture group. So `@(...)` instead of `(@...)`.

Then add the `@` as a literal inside the replacement string wherever it is needed. Meaning that `/profile/$1` stays the same, but the anchor contents becomes `@$1`.

Alternatively you could use `$&` (whole match) instead of `@$1`.

```js
const text = 'test @username'

const a = text.replace(/@([a-z_\d]+)/ig, '<a class="tag_user" href="/profile/$1" >@$1</a> ')
console.log(a)

const b = text.replace(/@([a-z_\d]+)/ig, '<a class="tag_user" href="/profile/$1" >$&</a> ')
console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the `@` and `username` separately.

```js
const text = 'test @username'
const replaced = text.replace(/(@)([a-z_\d]+)/ig, '<a class="tag_user" href="/profile/$2" >$1$2</a> ')
console.log(replaced)
```